# Writing and Reading Data to an NSMutableArray at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, nsmutablearray, streaming

I am trying to make a progressive download audio player that will store as much as of the audio while playing it.

The format of the audio is stream optimized `m4a`.

For this problem I thought get the audio packets with a streamer into the memory, dont save it to anyfile in order to keep things faster.

And by the nature of m4a files I can't write and read the file at the same time from disk anyways...

So I stream and parse audiopackets from a remote source then put them into a `Singleton` `NSMutableArray`...

While streamer downloads the audiopackets, player reads and play audio packets from `NSMutableArray` at the same time...

Average file has around 11000 audiopackets so the count of the array reaches to 11000.

```
    NSMutableDictionary * myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSData *inputData = [NSData dataWithBytes:inInputData length:inPacketDescriptions[i].mDataByteSize];
    [myDict setObject:inputData forKey:@"inInputData"];


    NSNumber *numberBytes = [NSNumber numberWithInt:inNumberBytes];
    [myDict setObject:numberBytes forKey:@"inNumberBytes"];

    NSNumber *numberPackets = [NSNumber numberWithInt:inNumberPackets];
    [myDict setObject:numberPackets  forKey:@"inNumberPackets"];


    NSNumber *mStartOffset = [NSNumber numberWithInt:inPacketDescriptions[i].mStartOffset];
    NSNumber *mDataByteSize = [NSNumber numberWithInt:inPacketDescriptions[i].mDataByteSize];
    NSNumber *mVariableFramesInPacket = [NSNumber numberWithInt:inPacketDescriptions[i].mVariableFramesInPacket];

    [myDict setObject:mStartOffset forKey:@"mStartOffset"];
    [myDict setObject:mDataByteSize forKey:@"mDataByteSize"];
    [myDict setObject:mVariableFramesInPacket forKey:@"mVariableFramesInPacket"];

    [sharedCache.baseAudioCache addObject:myDict];
```

My question is at some point will I encounter deadlocks?
Is this a good practice for audio streaming?

Comment: I am not sure about audio streaming, but I try not to read from a mutable object for that very reason.  Periodically, why not create an immutable copy to read from and continue writing to the mutable version?

Comment: You won't deadlock because you aren't locking - but you may very well corrupt the array by updating it from multiple threads (you don't show where you are removing the data, so I can only assume multiple threads are involved).  You can use a serial dispatch queue to ensure that updates are performed from a single thread.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not removing any data, when the player finishes reading the last packet I will delete the whole array. Streamer where data populated into array has its own thread, and I am planning to make the reader/player to has its own thread

Comment: @JoshGafni good suggestion but wouldnt that be too costly, in terms of memory allocations and cpu usage ?

Comment: If you only write to the array in one place then you will be OK, although you need to consider what happens if the stream stalls - if the "reader" catches up with the "writer", how do you block the reader and notify it when more data arrives?

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend to use NSArrays after you've built the NSMutableArray.

You can synchronize to lock the NSMutableArray too.

```
@synchronized(yourMutableArray) {
   [yourMutableArray stuffMethod];
}
```

Comment: A serial dispatch queue is probably better than @synchronised

Comment: wouldnt `@synchronized()` blocks the array pointer? what happens when writing data and reading it happens exactly at the same time from two different threads?

Comment: @Paulw11, A serial dispatch may be better. (maybe [dispatch_barrier_async()](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_barrier_async) )

I'd still just stay away from NSMutableArrays.